# While (multiple conditions) Complexity Analysis

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

It is obvious that a while (i < k) will run k items -- or not, depending on the starting value of i.

But what if I have a while loop such as:

```
while (counter != k && !found) {
   if (some condition)
     found = true;
   else
     counter++;
}
```

How would I calculate the worst case time complexity if I don't know when found will be set as true?

Comment: The complexity depends on the remaining code an variable values. Please [edit] your question to include the full code you have so we know what the values for `k` are and what the condition in the `if()` statement is.

Comment: Worst case `found` is never true since that ends the loop.

Comment: @Progman But the variable values change depending on the users input. Isn't there a general way to express this? Like a for loop runs from 0 to n even though we don't know what n exactly is.

Comment: @Neil So does this mean the worst case is n? I can't wrap my head on how I would write a mathematical model for this.

Comment: @MikeJohnson You can convert it to a `for` loop, specially since it looks like it is one in disguise.

Comment: Since we have worst case, `found` is false, you can optimize it out. Assuming `counter` is 0, it just becomes a loop to `k`. No `n` is present.

Comment: @Neil This is incorrect. Without more information about the condition, it could be `true`, or `counter< k` - and then the complexity will be `O(1)`.

Comment: @amit good call. I think that I'm assuming `counter == 0`, `not some condition` is satisfiable for all `[0, k-1]` some way, and evaluates always in `O(1)` to be tight. This is justifiable but should probably be noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of the above loop will be `O(k)` and it is irrespective of the `found` variable. As in the worst case the count will run till `k` and that will be the average case as well.

Comment: I disagree that it's irrespective of `found`, it is very much so. Assume `(some condition)` is actually `counter < k` or something else that meets in sublinear time. In this case, the complexity will be `O(time until some condition fulfilled)`. Generally speaking, since the loop depends on two condition happening, the lower of them is the actual complexity, or in other words `O(min{k, time to meet condition})`.

Comment: Though technically speaking, big O is giving upper bound only, and indeed an*upper bound* will be `O(k)` - but the bound might not be tight, and the reasoning does not indicate it. `O(k^2)` is also an upper bound to this code (Assuming of course `counter < k` initially....)