# What is time complexity of for loop of multiple conditions

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to develop a solution to decrease the time complexity of O(n^2) or O(n*m) algorithm to O(n) or O(n+m) algorithm. For example:

```js
    let arr = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]];
    let x = 0;
    let len = getArrayMaxLength (arr) //Get the maximum length of a 2d array which in this example is 8.
    for (let i = 0; i < len && x < arr.length; ++i) {
        print (arr [x][(i % arr [x].length);
        if ((i + 1) % arr [x].length == 0) {
          ++x;
          if (x != arr.length) i = -1;
        }
    }
```

I'm having problem to determine the Big-O of this algorithm as i have never dealt with loop with multiple conditions that much. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374640/while-multiple-conditions-complexity-analysis) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19564/complexity-analysis-of-while-loop-with-two-conditions) and still don't get quite right. From what i understand the time-complexity will be O(n+m). Where n is [arr.length] and m is [len] which is the output of a function getArrayMaxLength as described above.

So to sum things up. What is the time complexity of the algorithm?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the body of your loop contains lots of conditionals but none of these conditionals add to the number of repetitions on the outer for-loop and they also don't do any computation that has a variable time based on some input, them you should consider the body as a constant, thus not influencing on the final big-O complexity.

Your assumption of O(m + n) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Note that every time the for loop reaches the end of an inner array, the counter (variable `i`) resets and you increase `x`, passing onto the next inner array. That means you go through every single element of your two-dimensional array, which the program output confirms.

Although `n+m` complexity may seem ok, it is actually a bad approximation. In practice, the complexity is always bigger because array lengths vary. Imagine that all the subarrays have the same length, so `n = m`. As you visit n elements for every of the n inner arrays, the total complexity would then be quadratic (`n*n`) and not linear. When you're working with big arrays this difference becomes very obvious.

In conclusion, the time complexity is `O(n*m)`.

Comment: I understand your perspective. So the problem seems with resetting the variable i. So in theory if i didn't reset i and i remove the condition that increment variable y, then it can be i suppose O(n). I will try another solution that resolve these problems. Thank you