# Can this solution replace O(n^2) or O(n*m) algorithm or is it still O(n^2) or O(n*m) algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I've asked a question in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68431701/what-is-time-complexity-of-for-loop-of-multiple-conditions) in which i asked about the time-complexity of an algorithm of a solution i was making to decrease O(n^2) or O(n*m) algorithm to O(n) or O(n+m) algorithm. The answers allowed to rethink my solution and came up with a new solution, which is:

```
function sumArrayLength (arr) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; sum += arr [i].length, ++i);
    return sum;
}

let arr = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8]];
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let len = sumArrayLength (arr); //return the sum of all subarrays length, which is 18 in this example.
for (let z = 0; z < len; ++z) {
    console.log (arr [x][y % arr[x].length]);
    if ((y + 1) % arr [x].length === 0) {
        ++x;
        y = 0;
    } else y++;
}
```

from the above code i believe that the time-complexity is O(n), as the conditions inside the loop does not affect the number of iterations of the loop.

So the questions are:
If is this not O(n) algorithm, what is the time-complexity of this algorithm?

If it is O(n), does it mean it is faster or same speed? I know that O(n) is faster than O(n^2) or O(n*m). The reason i ask this is i have expanded the outer loop iteration to match nested loop iteration, or am i interpreting thing wrong?

Sorry for the long thread and thank you.

Comment: I would say the sumArrayLength is O(n) with n the number of rows and the other loop is O(m) with m the number of elements.

Comment: If `.length` method is O(1), then your for-loop part is O(n).  But the entire script is O(nm) because of the `arr` construction part: `let arr = [[1,2,3],...`.

Comment: You should define what `n` and `m` are.

Comment: @trincot
If you mean what are n and m in the question, in that case i would say n is the size of the 2d array and m is the size of each subarray.

like if we implemented the above algorithm in a nested loop format, it will look like this:
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
  for (let y = 0; y < arr [i].length; print (arr [i][y]), ++y);

if you mean my solution, i would say n is the total sum of all subarrays size in the second for loop where to treat it as O(n) operation and m will be the size of 2d array in the first array in sumArrayLength function.

Comment: But if `m` is the size of each subarray, then they should all have the same sizes. Or do you mean that `m` is the *greatest* among all subarray sizes? It would be more accurate if you would define a variable as being the total number of values in the 2D array. If you call that `k`, then the algorithm is O(k). Your question would be less confusing if there was a clear, single definition of `n` and `m` (in the question).